# Usar el modelo User.php por defecto de laravel para relacionar con otros modelos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7, model

Quiero utilizar el modelo User por defecto de laravel para relacionarlo con otros modelos que he creado (roles y dependencias), no tengo idea si esto es posible ya que el User.php por defecto extiende de Authenticatable y no de Model.

He creado un modelo Usuario con el siguiente contenido:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class usuario extends Model{
    public function roles(){
        return $this->belongTo(rol::class);        
    }

    public function dependencias(){
        return $this->belongTo(dependencia::class);        
    }    
}
```

Y quiero reutilizar el modelo User.php que se crea por defecto:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable{
    use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

}
```

Comment: Y.... ¿cuál es el problema? ¿qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Lo que quiero es tener un solo modelo llamado User.php que es el que tiene laravel por defecto, ya que actualmente tengo dos modelos, el User.php (por defecto) y el Usuario.php que yo he creado, no sé como hacer que una clase con el mismo nombre herede de dos métodos distintos (Authenticatable y Model) o si es posible hacer eso.

Comment: No veo aquí ningún problema por resolver. ¿Cuál es el inconveniente?

Comment: Funciona bien tal como lo tengo ahora pero quiero usar el mismo modelo para el login y para relacionarlo en la DB.
Ya que si copio el primer código dentro del segundo me marca un error.
Es decir quiero algo masomenos así:
    class User extends Authenticatable extends model

Comment: ¿qué error aparece?

Answer (score 3):

> Este es un error tipográfico, pero voy a explicarle al OP cómo revisar la herencia en futuras ocasiones.

El problema que se plantea aquí es poder utilizar el modelo User que viene incluido por defecto en Laravel 5.x para relacionarlo con cualquier otro método, lo cual es posible sin hacer nada «raro».

El OP argumenta que dicho modelo no extiende la clase Model, puesto que él ve en el código que extiende a Authenticatable, que no es más que un alias de la clase User del framework:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
 ....
```

Al revisar la clase User del framework, nos encontramos con que dicha clase extiende a Database\Eloquent\Model (lo cual lo hace igual a los demás modelos), y además utiliza varios traits, necesarios para el manejo típico de usuarios (autenticación, password, etc...)

**vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.php**

```
class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, MustVerifyEmail;
}
```

---

En ese orden de ideas, el modelo User puede ser relacionado como cualquier otro, esto gracias a la clase abstracta Model y a los traits que utiliza:

```
abstract class Model implements ArrayAccess, Arrayable, Jsonable, JsonSerializable, QueueableEntity, UrlRoutable
{
    use Concerns\HasAttributes,
        Concerns\HasEvents,
        Concerns\HasGlobalScopes,
        Concerns\HasRelationships,
        Concerns\HasTimestamps,
        Concerns\HidesAttributes,
        Concerns\GuardsAttributes,
        ForwardsCalls;

    ....
```

Por último, toda esta confusión sobre si el modelo User puede relacionarse o no, es generada porque el OP olvidó poner una **s** en el nombre del método que define la relación:

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsTo(rol::class);        
}

public function dependencias(){
    return $this->belongsTo(dependencia::class);        
}
```

El nombre correcto del método es **belongsTo()**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships